# Starting and stopping a node script from the web

Tags: node.js

I have a node script I'm working on that connects to an IRC channel for twitch.tv and responds to commands, as well as moderates chat lines that are being sent by other users connected.

Currently I open a terminal to the file location and run `node app.js` to start the IRC connection. But this runs on my mac and I use my PC to play games and watch the chat, so I have to have the Mac next to me to start and stop the IRC chat client app.

I want to move this to a web server where I can log in and start or stop the chat client app from the website, so I don't have to have the Mac next to me all the time.

What would be the best way to go about this?

If you want to see the script I'm working with you can find it here

https://github.com/Jordan4jc/super-fly-twitch-bot

Comment: You could also just SSH into the Mac when you want to start or stop the script. You don't need to write a single line of code for that.

Comment: Does the mac have to be on for that to work? Or will it work if it's asleep, it's a Macbook.

Comment: The Mac has to be on, but you can use Wake-on-LAN to wake it up. The same will be the case if you write a web server to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an HTTP server and listen on a port (if you don't mind overkill, express.js could make things easier for you). This server would contain configurations for the URL, authentication, etc. Within the callback that you provide to a URL path, you could close the IRC channels, database connections, and call `process.exit(0)` once you're confident that you've done everything necessary and you're sure it's what you want.

Comment: I think I understand how that can work now. I thought about express but was blanking on the actual implementation a bit, I'll have to tweak my app but I think you're right on that.

Comment: I just realised: if you're looking for a quick solution you could just SSH into your Mac @Jordan

Comment: Could to elaborate a little more on this though? Are you talking about setting up an end point the starts the chat client and one that stops it? Or are you says I can setup an endpoint that starts an entire script and one that exits the script?

Comment: @Jordan: If you want to be able to restart the chat client then having endpoints to start/stop the chat client would be preferable. If you just want to be able to exit the script then having a single endpoint to do that would be fine

Answer (score 0):

You can use [socket.io](http://socket.io/) as a way to send signals in real time to the application.